# syntax error near unexpected token `;&' and `cat &lt;&lt; EOF &gt; /etc/ld.so.conf.d/firefox.conf'

Tags: bash, sh

I got an error ./firefoxinstall.sh: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `;&'
./firefoxinstall.sh: line 22:`cat << EOF > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/firefox.conf' when I run `bash ./firefoxinstall.sh` .
I wrote firefoxinstall.sh,

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=/usr/local
function init()
{
export installroot=$TARGET/src
export workpath=$TARGET
yum –assumeyes install make libjpeg-devel libpng-devel \
libtiff-devel gcc libffi-devel gettext-devel libmpc-devel \
libstdc++46-devel xauth gcc-c++ libtool libX11-devel \
libXext-devel libXinerama-devel libXi-devel libxml2-devel \
libXrender-devel libXrandr-devel libXt dbus-glib \
libXdamage libXcomposite
mkdir -p $workpath
mkdir -p $installroot
cd $installroot
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=“$workpath/lib/pkgconfig”
PATH=$workpath/bin:$PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH PATH
bash -c “
cat &lt;&lt; EOF &gt; /etc/ld.so.conf.d/firefox.conf
$workpath/lib
$workpath/firefox
EOF
ldconfig
”
}
function finish()
{
cd $workpath
wget -r –no-parent –reject “index.html*” -nH –cut-dirs=7 http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/32.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-32.0.tar.bz2
tar xvf firefox*
cd bin
ln -s ../firefox/firefox
ldconfig
}
function install()
{
wget $1
FILE=basename $1
if [ ${FILE: -3} == “.xz” ]
then tar xvfJ $FILE
else tar xvf $FILE
fi
SHORT=${FILE:0:4}*
cd $SHORT
./configure –prefix=$workpath
make
make install
ldconfig
cd ..
}
init
install ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.xz
install https://www.dropbox.com/s/m605fa6jgff7kcb/freetype-2.4.9.tar.gz?dl=0
install http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/release/fontconfig-2.9.0.tar.gz
install http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.32/glib-2.32.3.tar.xz
install http://cairographics.org/releases/pixman-0.26.0.tar.gz
install http://cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.12.2.tar.xz
install http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/pango/1.30/pango-1.30.0.tar.xz
install http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/atk/2.4/atk-2.4.0.tar.xz
install http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gdk-pixbuf/2.26/gdk-pixbuf-2.26.1.tar.xz
install http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gtk+/2.24/gtk+-2.24.10.tar.xz
finish

adds the /usr/local/bin to your path by updating your .bashrc file.

cat &lt;&lt; EOF &gt;&gt; ~/.bashrc
PATH=/usr/local/bin:\$PATH
export PATH
EOF
```

I really cannot understand why such a syntax error happens.I did not think syntax error is near line 22.How can I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: a great tool to check: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you copied this code from some web page?

To fix that error, just replace all occurrences of `&lt;` with `<` and all occurrences of `&gt;` with `>`.

I see such sequences on line 22 (`cat &lt;&lt; EOF &gt; /etc/ld.so.conf.d/firefox.conf`) and also a line next to the end (`cat &lt;&lt; EOF &gt;&gt; ~/.bashrc`).

You should also replace the typographic quotes (`“ ”`) with plain double quotes (`"`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Is your answer's meaning I should change the code into `cat < EOF > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/firefox.conf` ?

Comment: `<<` : `cat << EOF > file` @user9619086

Comment: Actually this is `cat << EOF >> ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is special character with special meaning.  You need to quote such characters to be able to use special characters in strings.

Do `man bash`, search for, "QUOTING".  Also available [online](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html).

The specific characters in your program that you need to fix are, '&' and ';'.  Both of these characters are special syntax that separate commands on the same line.  For more information, `man bash`.  Or, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html).